# Relation between local ring of regular variety and local ring of regular subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a regular affine variety and $Y \subseteq X$ be a regular subvariety such that $\dim(X)-\dim(Y)=1$. If $y \in Y,$ can we say  $\frac{\mathcal{O}_{X,y}}{<c>} \cong \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} $ for some $c \in (\mathfrak{m}_{X,y}\setminus \mathfrak{m}^2_{X,y})$, where $\mathfrak{m}_{X,y}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,y}$?

I proved that $\frac{\mathcal{O}_{X,y}}{<c>}$ is regular ring and it's dimension is $dim(X)−1$ when $c$ is in $\mathfrak{m}_{X,y}\setminus \mathfrak{m}^2_{X,y}$. I don't know how to proceed from this part. 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: This information and where you're stuck in the rest of the problem should be in your post, not just the comments. Please make an [edit] to improve your question.

Comment: You could try looking at Proposition 2.2.4 in [Bruns and Herzog](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511608681).